# Why am I getting row inside a map function while using flex-col?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, tailwind-css

I am trying to build a chord visualizer in React and tailwind. The goal is to have five columns- the first four columns each have a ball on the left border- and the last column (fifth) has balls on the left and right border. This way, I can represent six balls on five columns just like other chord charts appear. I have a good idea of how I can translate the balls in tailwind- I just need to get the divs in columns, if that makes sense.

The map function I am using does let me conditionally show the ball on frets but I cannot access the last column. If you run my code, you can see the last row being colored red- I just need to color the last column as red. This has tripped me up for days- any pointers?

Below is the code inside my App component:

```
const App = () => {

    //these are the positions of the dots on the frets
    const frets = [0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0]

    //some jsx to show ball if the fret number matches the current box
    const ball = (<div className='-translate-x-1/2 bg-amber-400 rounded-full h-8 w-8'></div>);

    return (<div className='flex flex-row'>
        {
            frets.map(
                e => {
                    return (<div className='flex flex-wrap flex-col'>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 0 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 1 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 2 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 3 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 4 ? (ball) : null}</div>

                        //I need to access the last column but setting the background to red-800 like this gives me the bottom row.
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center bg-red-800'>{e == 5 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                    </div>
                    )
                }
            )
        }

    </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried using map function and a for loop but both gave exact same results. I am new to frontend, so I have no idea why applying flex-col inside the map function isn't working.

```
 frets.map(
                e => {
                    return (<div className='flex flex-wrap flex-col'>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 0 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 1 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 2 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 3 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{e == 4 ? (ball) : null}</div>

                        //I need to access the last column but setting the background to red-800 like this gives me the bottom row.
                        <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center bg-red-800'>{e == 5 ? (ball) : null}</div>
                    </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get index of the `Array` by `.map` method, just add `index` to the method, like this :

```
frets.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-wrap flex-col'>
      <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{index == 0 && ball}</div>
      <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{index == 1 && ball}</div>
      <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{index == 2 && ball}</div>
      <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{index == 3 && ball}</div>
      <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center'>{index == 4 && ball}</div>
      <div className='border-2 border-white h-12 w-12 bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center bg-red-800'>{index == 5 && ball}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### NOTE

Didn't use the `jsx` in variable; you can use the inline function or [`useFactory` hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/createFactory#createfactory) or instead create the external `Component` for `ball` jsx element.

#### NOTE

In `tailwindcss@3.*` the static generation styles and classnames added, so when you using the dynamic classname, the class didn't generate with `tailwind`, instead use older version or `another` `xwind`.

Enjoy Developing !